# Getting text value from alert box

Tags: swift, alert

I'm having problems getting a text fields value from a UIAlertController. I am getting the value, but It seems to be executing my code in the wrong order. In the function below, I expect the function call to return a string, but the value is not set at the time the function returns.

```
@IBAction func btnSaveSession(sender: AnyObject) {

    //Prompt user to enter session name

    var sessionName: String = ""

    sessionName = promptUserToEnterSessionName("Save Session", message: "Please enter the name of your custom session below.");

    print("session Name: " + sessionName)

    //Save session to firebase.

    //redirect to create session controller.
}

func promptUserToEnterSessionName(title: String, message: String) -> String{

    var sessionName: String = ""

    //1. Create the alert controller.
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .Alert)

    //2. Add the text field. You can configure it however you need.
    alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler({ (textField) -> Void in
        textField.text = "Enter session name."
    })

    //3. Grab the value from the text field, and print it when the user clicks OK.
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
        let textField = alert.textFields![0] as UITextField
        print("Text field: \(textField.text)")
        sessionName = textField.text!
    }))

    // 4. Present the alert.
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    return sessionName

}
```

If anyone is having problems understanding my question, please comment and I will do my best to explain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your ok action handler(closure) will call when you click on ok button. so instead of assign value to local variable sessionName , make a  sessionName variable in class.

```
class YourClass {
var sessionName: String?

...

@IBAction func btnSaveSession(sender: AnyObject) {

//Prompt user to enter session name

promptUserToEnterSessionName("Save Session", message: "Please enter the name of your custom session below.");

}


func promptUserToEnterSessionName(title: String, message: String) {


//1. Create the alert controller.
let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .Alert)

//2. Add the text field. You can configure it however you need.
alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler({ (textField) -> Void in
    textField.text = "Enter session name."
})

//3. Grab the value from the text field, and print it when the user clicks OK.
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
    let textField = alert.textFields![0] as UITextField
    print("Text field: \(textField.text)")
    self.sessionName = textField.text!
    self.testDemo()
}))

// 4. Present the alert.
self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)


}

fun TestDemo() {
print("session Name: " + self.sessionName)

//Save session to firebase.

//redirect to create session controller.

}
 }
```

Comment: This still gives me the same problem. sessionName gets printed before the value is assigned.

Comment: yeah right it will print  session value before clicking. you can call function from addAction and do your work there.

Comment: or you can pass direct value in testDemo , so you don't need to make var in class. For e.g alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
    let textField = alert.textFields![0] as UITextField
    print("Text field: \(textField.text)")
    self.testDemo(textField.text!)
}))
 or can get this in TestDemo
func testDemo(sessionName: String) {
}

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Callback to get the value, like this:

```
func AlertPrompt(vista:UIViewController, titulo:String , mensaje:String, aceptar:String, completion: @escaping (_ resultado: String)->()) {
        let miAlerta = UIAlertController(title: titulo, message: mensaje, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        miAlerta.addTextField(configurationHandler: {
            (textField) -> Void in
        })
        let okBoton = UIAlertAction(title: aceptar, style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: {
            (action) -> Void in
            let result = miAlerta.textFields![0] as UITextField
            // You return the value here
            completion(result.text! as String)
        })
        miAlerta.addAction(okBoton)
        let cancelBoton = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil)
        miAlerta.addAction(cancelBoton)
        vista.present(miAlerta, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

And call the function like this:

```
AlertPrompt(vista: self, titulo: "Title", mensaje: "some message", aceptar: "Acept"){(resultado)->() in
     print(resultado)
}
```

That works perfect for me, hope this help

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
let textField = alert.textFields![0] as UITextField
print("Text field: \(textField.text)")
sessionName = textField.text!
```

will be called only at the moment the button corresponding to the defined action is clicked. So at the moment of creation the UIAlertController it's not called.

Read about blocks in Swift, it should be clearer then.